# Ksh script to transform a list

Tags: unix, ksh

After applying some commands I have a data set as below

```
graph_name=abc
group_name=def
factory=xyz
export a=1
export b=2
export c=3
```

Now how can i acheieve the below output

```
graph_name=abc
export a=1
export b=2
export c=3
```

I need all the export statements in addition with just graph_name containing record.

Comment: Do you only want the first "graph_name" line because its value contains the exported variable names?

Comment: no its not like that I asked this as per my requirement.Thanks Jack.

Comment: Ah, I read "group_name" as another "graph_name" record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/^graph_name=/p' -e '/^export /p' your-file
```

This doesn't print by default (`-n`); it then explicitly prints those lines that match what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A simple grep command:

```
grep -w -e "graph_name=" -w -e "export" tmp FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

some awk solutions:

```
awk '/^graph_name=/ || /^export /' filename
awk '/^(graph_name|export)\>/' filename
awk -F '[= ]' '$1 == "graph_name" || $1 == "export"' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try egrep to match any of a number of patterns separated by the pipe symbol. Here I am looking for lines beginning with "graph_name" or "export":

```
egrep "^graph_name|^export" your_file
```